# CSS file is linked but doesnt affect the page

Tags: html, css, pug

I linked the css file and in the browser inspect mode i can see and open it but it doesn't affect the page.

This is my layout.pug file:

```
  1 doctype html
  2 html
  3   head
  4     link(href="/stylesheets/app.css", type="text/css",  ref="stylesheet")
  5     block title
  6   body
  7     block content
```

This is my index.pug file:

```
  1 extends layout
  2
  3 block title
  4   title Index
  5
  6 block content
  7   h1 Books
  8
  9   div
 10     a(href='new') New Book
 11
 12   table
 13     th Title
 14     th Author
 15     each book in books
 16       tr
 17         td= book.title
 18         td= book.author
 19         td (show)
 20         td (delete)
```

This is my app.css file:

```
  1 h1 {
  2   color: blue;
  3 }
```

What am I missing? Why the header didn't change colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error I spot is a simple typo: The attribute of `link` is [`rel`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel) (not `ref`).

Another thing that caught my eye (but is is just a suspicion) is about the `href` attribute: Is the heading slash correct?

Comment: Thank you alot. It was the spelling mistake(rel). You just saved me sitting here holding my head for 2 hours trying every possible path. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check your file in the browser and make sure that your css file is found. If not check your spelling or if the location of the file is correct